# WERR_ACCESS_DENIED - While rebooting Windows with Linux over LAN

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, redhat, rhel4

We recently lost one of our Windows 2K8 servers while switching from Static to DHCP after a DHCP release command was inadvertently called.  The server was still active but we were no longer aware of the IP to access.  The FQDN was also in the process of being updated leaving us helpless.  We attempted to reboot the windows machine by using a private link from a RHEL box using the following command:

```
# net rpc shutdown -r XXX.XXX.X.X -U [USERNAME]
```

We received a WERR_ACCESS_DENIED error.  After a visit to the datacenter, we were able to get the machine online.  But has anyone come across the net rpc shutdown error before?  It would be helpful to know we could rely on using a Private Link to fix future issues.

I have researched the above error and was only able to find information on "Simple File Sharing" which does not exist in any Windows Server loads that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully got rid of WERR_ACCESS_DENIED by creating new registry from elevated cmd.

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

after which I have called from linux terminal

net rpc service list -I xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U domain\\user%password

Answer found in german language at:
[UAC-Filter for windows](https://www.windowspro.de/tipp/uac-filter-fuer-windows-fernwartung-abschalten)